# Translation of some .htaccess regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on learning regex, do you think anyone could help translate what the following .htaccess excerpt is doing in logical terminology?

```
301 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
302 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
303 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(admin|scripts|api)(.*)$ [NC]
304 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(.*)$ [NC]
305 RewriteRule ^(.*)$    index.php?subdomain=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Automated regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com), which can help in many ways, such as optimizing or understanding complex regular expressions